# How to consume message from Kafka topic using some filter?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am writing a simple Kafka producer-consumer program in Java, where I have produced data like this:

- key:"a" value:"{25,223,465}"
- key:"a" value:"{26,323,56}"
- key:"a" value:"{62,256,652}"
- key:"a" value:"{26,227,42}"
- key:"b" value:"{4352,234,65342}"
- key:"b" value:"{243,22347,434}"

I am able to consume the messages using `consumer.poll(10000)`, But now I want to consume data something like how many `a` records and how many `b` records are present in the Kafka topic.

If I relate this to SQL

```
select count(*) from 'mytopic' where key='a'

select count(*) from 'mytopic' where key='b'
```

Please provide me code in java if possible

Comment: Sounds like you might be interested in using ksqlDB

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yeah maybe, But don't know how to use this in Java code. can you please provide some souce

Comment: I trust your ability to find and search ksqlDB examples on its website... KsqlDB uses sql syntax, but it has a REST API you can use via Java. As answered, though, a plain Kafka consumer isn't meant to be used in the way you're asking for doing aggregations - you'll need another tool

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thx

Answer (score 1):

Kafka doesn't work in this way, a consumer just reads from the latest committed offset in a partition (or from the beginning) and sequentially all the messages.
What you can do is filtering in your application.
For your purpose, instead of writing an application using just consumer API you can use a Kafka Streams API based application that provides you a DSL for doing operating like mapping, filtering, ... really easily.
More information here:

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/